# Solaris 10 user does not inherit privileges from user_attr

Tags: permissions, ftp, solaris

I have created a user called manager and set the /etc/user_attr file to allow net_privaddr privileges. But when I log into a shell as that user I'm not seeing those privileges granted. This is causing a "FTP Server start Error java.net.BindException: Permission denied." when I try to start an FTP server on port 21. Is there anything else I can check?

```
# grep manager /etc/user_attr
manager::::type=normal;defaultpriv=basic,net_privaddr
#
# su - manager
$ ppriv $$
24180:  -sh
flags = <none>
        E: basic
        I: basic
        P: basic
        L: all
$ exit
#
#
# su manager 
$ ppriv $$
24193:  sh
flags = <none>
        E: basic
        I: basic
        P: basic
        L: all
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about your setup. As I already replied, I do not reproduce this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your setup works just fine here:

```
# grep manager /etc/user_attr
manager::::type=normal;defaultpriv=basic,net_privaddr
# 
# su - manager
Oracle Corporation      SunOS 5.10      Generic Patch   January 2005
$ ppriv $$
1271:   -sh
flags = <none>
        E: basic,net_privaddr
        I: basic,net_privaddr
        P: basic,net_privaddr
        L: all
$ cat /etc/release
                    Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10x_u9wos_14a X86
     Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 11 August 2010
```

You need to provide more clues about your configuration, the release you are running.